# Determinant of a random symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, random-matrices

I am trying to determine the determinant of the following uniformly distributed random symmetric matrix $A$ with zero mean.

\begin{equation}
A=
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & \cos \alpha_{12} & \cos \alpha_{13} & \dots &\cos \alpha_{1N} \\
 \cos \alpha_{12}& 1 & \cos \alpha_{23} & \dots &\cos \alpha_{2N} \\
 \cos \alpha_{13} & \cos \alpha_{23} & 1 & \dots &\cos \alpha_{3N} \\
       \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \quad & \vdots \\
  \cos \alpha_{1N} & \cos \alpha_{2N} & \cos \alpha_{3N} & \dots & 1\\
 \end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}
Where each vectors are linearly independent and $\alpha_{ij} \in [-0.5,0.5]$, for all $i,j=1,2,3,\dots,N$.

Any valuable resource or help is appreciated.

**Numerical Results**: So far I have the following results:

1. As $N$ goes to infinity, the expected value of the determinant approaches zero. 
   For instance, computing $k\times k$ determinants, for $2<=k<=N(=30)$ i.e. for $k=2$,
   \begin{equation}
   A=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \cos \alpha_{12} & \cos \alpha_{13} & \dots &\cos \alpha_{1N} \\
    \cos \alpha_{12}& 1 & \cos \alpha_{23} & \dots &\cos \alpha_{2N} \\
    \end{pmatrix} 
   \end{equation}
   then $AA^T$ will be a $2\times 2$ matrix. This gives the following result.
   [Expected value of the determinant for $2<=k<=30$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjD1B.png)
2. The value of the determinant for a particular value $k$ increases as N goes to infinity. For example when $K=2$, the determinant of the $2\times 2$ matrix for N=10,20 and 30 respectively is $0.05210<0.05301<0.05329$.

**Analytical Explanation**
I am looking for an analytical explanation to support the above numerical result.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: What do you mean by "predict"?

Comment: You wrote symmetric matrix. Thus we should assume $\alpha_{ij}=\alpha_{ji}$.

Comment: If you're talking about a random matrix you should specify the probability distribution for the parameters $\alpha_{ij}$.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response guys. Based on your comments I edited my question. I hope everything is clear now

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Posted some updates